# Как сделать проверку на завершенный заказ WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Я пытаюсь написать простой плагин который бы отображал информацию это новый покупатель или вернувшийся и считал количество заказов со статусом completed. Для этого я пишу следующий код:

```php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Kasha returning customers
 * Description: Displays information returning customer or new, and also displays the number of completed orders
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Me
 * License: GPLv2 or later
 */


add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'render_customer_is_new_field' );

function render_customer_is_new_field($order)
{

    $args = array(
        'status' => 'completed',
        'return' => 'ids',
    );
    
    if ( $order->get_user_id() !== 0 ) {
        $args['customer_id'] = $order->get_customer_id();
    } else {
        $args['customer'] = $order->get_billing_email();
    }
    
    $customer_has_existing_orders  = wc_get_orders( $args );

    $orders_count = count($customer_has_existing_orders);

    $markData = ( (int)count($customer_has_existing_orders) >= 2 )
        ? array('status-processing', 'Returning customer')
        : array('status-on-hold', 'New Customer');


    echo '
    <p class="kasha-customer-counter" style="float: left">
        <mark class="order-status '. $markData[0] .'">
            <span>'. $markData[1] .' <strong style="color:#ff0000;font-weight: 900;"> '. $orders_count .'</strong></span>
        </mark>
    </p>
    ';
}
```

Однако функция wc_get_orders не срабатывает. Если выводить через var_dump(wc_get_orders()) результат просто NULL, если вывожу var_dump(wc_get_orders($args)) получаю такой результат - https://prnt.sc/10aj9vb , даже не пойму что это за цифры так как это и не id клиента и не номер заказа..
Как выполнить проверку есть ли у данного пользователя больше 2х заказов со статусом completed и посчитать у этого же пользователя сколько всего завершенных заказов?

Comment: судя по вашему скриншоту вы получаете корректный результат, у вас в аргументах передается параметр 'return' => 'ids' когда есть этот параметр то возврщается массив id заказов, на вашем скриншоте у пользователя их пять

Comment: @DarthKYL спасибо, что прояснили что это)Однако суть вопроса не меняется)Считает все заказы, а не только те что со статусом completed, не могу понять почему так происходит

Comment: Вы уверены что такой статус есть? И что он пишется без префикса? Посмотрите [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_order_statuses) и [тут](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query#general) больше про сам wc_get_orders()